# Store images from url in cache and use them as thumbnail or placeholder like whatsapp.

Tags: android

I am developing story feature app like instagram or whatsapp but I got stuck somewhere. I am getting image thumbnail from server as URL but when I try to use it . It take some time to load that image.So I want to Load add thumbnail images from url in previous activity and then set that thumbnail from cache.How I can store url images in cache Hashmap or arraylist to use them in next activity.Please help.I am in trouble right now.

Comment: have you tried Picasso Image catching library ?

Comment: use Image Loading library like Glide, Picasso

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for catching the image from URL.

Comment: I am using Glide for catching the image from URL but Its showing loader for first time.Now I am trying to save image  FutureTarget<File> future = Glide.with(mContext)
                                        .load(userStoryList.get(i).getMediaUrl())
                                        .downloadOnly(500, 500); but its not working.